# check time between 9.30 to 4 ruby

Tags: ruby, time

i have a code that erroneously produces it and i am thinking that there must be  a better way to check for time >9.30 am and time <4 pm
any  ideas is highly appreicated.

```
def checkTime

   goodtime=false
   if(Time.now.hour>9 and Time.now.min>30) then

     if(Time.now.hour<16) then
       goodtime=true

     else
       # do nothing
     end
   elsif Time.now.hour>9 and Time.now.hour<16 then
     goodtime=true

   else
      # do nothing
   end
   return goodtime

 end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
t = Time.now

Range.new(
  Time.local(t.year, t.month, t.day, 9),
  Time.local(t.year, t.month, t.day, 16, 30)
) === t
```

Comment: I can't get this one to work in 2.0.0, as it reports: `TypeError: can't iterate from Time`. Converting the range endpoints with `.to_i`, and then comparing with `t.to_i` works, however.

Answer (score 5):

```
def check_time(t=Time.now)
  early = Time.new(t.year, t.month, t.day, 9, 30, 0, t.utc_offset)
  late  = Time.new(t.year, t.month, t.day, 16, 0, 0, t.utc_offset)
  t.between?(early, late)
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i had some issue like ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (7 for 0)
        from (irb):7:in `initialize'
        from (irb):7:in `new'
        from (irb):7

Answer (score 4):

Just:

```
def checkTime
  return ((Time.now.hour * 60) + Time.now.min) >= 570 && ((Time.now.hour * 60) + Time.now.min) < 960
end
```

Comment: i need the minute to be also greater than 30 if the hour is <10. is there a way to compare hour and minute  as 1 object

Comment: I get `NoMethodError: undefined method \`minutes' for 2012-04-10 18:19:18 +0200:Time`

Comment: What about ((Time.now.hour * 60) + Time.now.min)?

Answer (score 4):

Working in a mixed version environment and needing this exact method here's what I put in my code:

```
if RUBY_VERSION == "1.9.3"
  def check_time(starthour,endhour,t=Time.now)
    early = Time.new(t.year, t.month, t.day, starthour, 0, 0)
    late  = Time.new(t.year, t.month, t.day, endhour, 0, 0)
    t.between?(early, late)
  end
elsif RUBY_VERSION == "1.8.7"
  def check_time(starthour,endhour,t=Time.now)
    early = Time.local(t.year, t.month, t.day, starthour, 0, 0)
    late  = Time.local(t.year, t.month, t.day, endhour, 0, 0)
    t.between?(early, late)
  end
end
```