# Custom Validator to Prevent an appointment from being scheduled too early in day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, datetime

I'm building a Rails 4 application, which has an Appointment model.  I'm trying to figure out how to write a custom validator to prevent users from scheduling appointments before 6:30 a.m. and after 9:00 p.m.  DateTime is the data type of my model's appointment_date field.

My initial thought is to write a method in my model to define the validation, but I don't know how to structure such a method, or if that is the best approach to solving the problem.

I've searched the Internet for clues on how to accomplish my objective, but didn't find anything helpful.  I would greatly appreciate any suggestions about how I can best do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own, the same way active record does. This results in clean, portable, easy to test custom validations. An example might look like:

create *app/validators/during_business_hours_validator.rb* with:

```
class DuringBusinessHoursValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    # example - do whatever you want here
    unless value.present? && during_business_hours(value)
      record.errors[attribute] << 'must be during business hours'
    end
  end

  def during_business_hours(time)
    # from http://stackoverflow.com/q/10090962/525478
    Range.new(
      Time.local(time.year, time.month, time.day, 6, 30),
      Time.local(time.year, time.month, time.day, 21)) === time
  end

end
```

then, in your model add:

```
validates :appointment_date,
          during_business_hours: true
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm learning Rails, and don't fully understand the advice especially the first method. I don't understand what that first method does or how it works. Do I substitute something for the "record, attribute, value" parts of the method?  Please explain what the first method does, and how I should use it. When you say "do whatever you want here," what do you mean?  What sort of stuff might I place in that part of the method relative to my objective?  Lastly, can I place this custom validator anywhere in the Rails file tree?  I really appreciate your help!