# Time range method not working in Rails 4/Ruby 2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need help troubleshooting a time range problem in a Rails 4/Ruby 2.0 application. In my Appointment model, I want to prevent users from making appointments outside of business hours, which are 6:30 a.m. to 9:00 p.m.  The model tracks appointment times in a column named appointment_date, which is of the DateTime data type.

I tried to solve the problem by placing the following methods in the app/validators directory:

```
class DuringBusinessHoursValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator

def validate_each(record, attribute, value)    
unless value.present? && during_business_hours(value)
record.errors[attribute] << 'must be during business hours (6:30 am - 9:00 pm)'
end
end

def during_business_hours(time)
# from http://stackoverflow.com/q/10090962/525478    
Range.new(
Time.local(time.year, time.month, time.day, 6, 30),
Time.local(time.year, time.month, time.day, 21, 0)) === time
end
end
```

I put the following code in my Appointment model:

```
validates :appointment_date, during_business_hours: true
```

However, Rails throws the following error:

```
TypeError in AppointmentsController#update
can't iterate from Time
```

When I remove one of the === signs in the method, Rails does not generate an error, but the code does not operate correctly.  When using ==, all appointments are restricted, even those that will occur between 6:30 am and 9:00 pm.

I read another Stackoverflow post where someone reported a problem executing the aforementioned method with Ruby 2.0.  The person stated they solved the issue by "converting the range endpoints with .to_i, and then comparing with t.to_i."  So, I changed the code in the second method as follows:

```
def during_business_hours(t)

t = Time.now

Range.new(
Time.local(t.year, t.month, t.day, 6, 30).to_i,
Time.local(t.year, t.month, t.day, 21).to_i
) === t.to_i
end
end
```

However, that change does not work.  It creates the opposite problem: Rails allows all appointments, regardless of hour.

Any ideas or suggestions for how I can troubleshoot further and solve the problem?  I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take advantage of the fact that DateTime objects support comparison. E.g.

```
   Time.local(2014, 12, 31, 6, 30) > Time.local(2015, 1, 1, 6, 30)
   => false
```

Hence you could rewrite the method `during_business_hours`:

```
   # Check if time `t` is between 6:30 and 21:00 of `t`'s day, a.k.a. in between business hours.
   # If that's the case, return true, otherwise false.
   def during_business_hours(t)
     if t < Time.local(t.year, t.month, t.day, 6, 30) ||
        t > Time.local(t.year, t.month, t.day, 21)
        return false
     else
        return true
     end
   end
```

Personally, your current code for that method is very hard to read, the new version is much clearer.

...and BTW, I would make it a `private` method.

```
def validate_each [snip]

private

def during_business_hours(t)
  [snip]
```

Comment: Thanks Kenny.  I'll check out your suggested code at my earliest opportunity.  Also,  thanks for the feedback on the readability of my code.  I'm learning to code in Rails & Ruby,  so I really appreciate the feedback.  Your code is clearer.  I hope it solves my problem.  I'll follow up after I try it.  THANKS!

Comment: You're welcome - there are many ways to solve a problem. Ruby is one of those languages where you can solve problem in a very readable way. You can hit me up on Twitter if you want to talk. http://twitter.com/meyerkenny

Comment: I made the changes to my app. No errors, but the range isn't working properly.  Users shouldn't be allowed to make appointments between the hours of 9:01 pm and 6:29 am.  However, the code restricts appointments between the hours of 12:00 am and 2:29 pm.  Currently, the earliest a user can make an appointment is 2:30 pm, but it should be 6:30 am.  The latest a user is being allowed to make an appointment is 11:59 pm, but it should be 8:59 pm.  The time is off 8 hours of the desired start & three hours of the end time for appointments.  Time.now.to.s shows correct time. What could be wrong?

Comment: Disregard my last post. I solved the time issue by placing my local time zone in the config.time_zone section of my application.rb file. Running rake time:zones:all produced a complete listing of time zones. Everything is working as expected now.  Thanks for your help Kenny!

Comment: I am glad you figured out the original error! Seems like your original code still can work?

Comment: Yeah, the original code works ... it was the time zone issue all along. I like the simplicity of your suggested code, and will use it. I learned a lot troubleshooting the error!